# dplyr filter() to remove consecutive duplicates - why is my very first row removed?

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I have a dataframe with GPS tracks. On some occasions, the GPS did not work properly and recorded two consecutive duplicate positions (exactly the same Lat and Long). I have found a way to remove the second of such duplicated consecutive locations using `dplyr::filter`, but for some reason the first row in my dataframe is also removed. If my first two rows are consecutive duplicates, both rows are removed.

Here some dummy data and the code I use:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = rep(c('B1', 'B2', 'B3', "B1"), each = 2),
                   var1 = rep(c('a', 'a', 'b', 'a'), times = 2), 
                   var2 = sample(1:20, 8))
data <- data %>% add_row(ID = "B9", var1 = "c", var2 = 12, .before = 1) %>% 
add_row(ID = "B8", var1 = "d", var2 = 12, .before = 1)


d2 <- data %>%
  filter(ID != lag(ID, 1)|var1 != lag(var1, 1))
```

For now, my solution is to add a dummy row before executing the code, but that seems daft.

Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what your lags produce to see why it's occurred.

```
 data %>%
   mutate(
     x1 = lag(ID, 1),
     x2= lag(var1, 1)
     )

  ID var1 var2   x1   x2
1 B1    a   17 <NA> <NA>
2 B1    a   10   B1    a
3 B2    b   18   B1    a
4 B2    a   16   B2    b
5 B3    a    7   B2    a
6 B3    a    1   B3    a
7 B1    b   20   B3    a
8 B1    a    4   B1    b
```

---

So if you want to do it by looking at the previous row you need to set the default.

```
 data %>%
  filter(ID != lag(ID, 1,default =  first(ID))|var1 != lag(var1, 1, default =first(var1)))
```

Comment: That helps to understand the issue, thanks very much @Quixotic22. But your code seems to produce the same as mine, i.e. the first row gets removed. Am I missing something?